# Virtual Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, virtualization

What would be a lightweight way to create a virtual Active Directory domain with a few fake users on Windows 7? I am wanting to test a small app that integrates with AD.

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) for Windows7

AD LDS is a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) directory service that provides flexible support for directory-enabled applications, without the dependencies that are required for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS). AD LDS provides much of the same functionality as AD DS, but it does not require the deployment of domains or domain controllers. In environments where AD DS exists, AD LDS can use AD DS for the authentication of Windows security principals. You can run multiple instances of AD LDS concurrently on a single computer, and have an independently managed schema for each AD LDS instance.

[x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/9/73982B95-A8C9-4B6C-BD85-6EC620BB0A7A/Windows6.1-KB975541-x86.msu), [x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/9/73982B95-A8C9-4B6C-BD85-6EC620BB0A7A/Windows6.1-KB975541-x64.msu)

Comment: Alvosu, a link alone doesn't help if no one knows what he is downloading.

Comment: Sorry, bugs in FF(

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an AD domain on Win7. Easiest way would be to use a virtual machine with an evaluation version of Win2008R2.

Edit: Apparently a subset of the functionality of an AD domain is available, see alvosu's post.